# how to enable "extended dns error" option in bind?

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to use "extended dns error" option on my recursive dns server. What config changes are required to enable EDE?

I am using BIND 9.16.18 as recursive server.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (enable Extended DNS Error codes aka RFC 8914) in current (september 2021) versions of Bind.

See https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/issues/1836

The feature is still being worked on, so it doesn't exist yet.

The current label on it is `9.19` so you might get that feature when that version of Bind is released, and you will then need to update your `9.16.18` version.

If you don't have a real specific constraint on Bind, other software do have it, for example `nsd` (see https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/nsd/rfc-compliance/)

Comment: I want to use this feature on recursive and found that unbound doesn't not supported this feature as nsd is for authoritative.

Comment: `unbound` is a recursive nameserver, as sibling of `nsd` and it fully supports RFC8914: https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/rfc-compliance/